# Make a folder for each line in a csv with its corresponding name?

Tags: python, pandas

csv has this structure:

```
col1
100
101
102
..
150
```

I want it to read each line and create a folder that there, will be created each folder for each line with the corresponding number as its name.
Also would be nice to store it in the Desktop.

Example:

```
New folder----100
          ----101
          ----102
              ..
```

What I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
df = pd.read_csv(path)
for i in df:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join())
```

Comment: `for i in df["col1"]:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(path, i))` ?

Comment: pandas is overkill here. The csv module (included in standard distributions would be enough)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
path = "Your_Desktop_Path"
df = pd.read_csv(path)
for i in df["col1"].astype(str):
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(path, i))
```

---

*Or if you just have a single column.*

```
import os

path = "Your_Desktop_Path"

with open(filename) as infile:
    next(infile) #Skip Header
    for line in infile:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(path, line.strip()))
```

Comment: TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'int'

Comment: `for i in df["col1"].astype(str):`

Comment: You missed one detail: 'The main folder that will have these.' It has to create a folder that will store there all these folders.

Comment: Can you make it store it in one new folder, all these folders?